# Starting netsh wlan start hostednetwork needs administrator privilege to run

Tags: java, windows, command, privileges

I want to access the command prompt of windows and run a command that starts `hostnetwork`, I can start it by hand, but I try to run it through Java.

This what I've tried

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c netsh wlan start hostednetwork");
```

But It gives this message:

> You must run this command from a command prompt with administrator privilege.

Any solution, or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: @jdero: need to run start command with administrator privilege.

Comment: It wasn't me. But it might be because people aren't understanding your question.

Comment: Why do you need to run it via `cmd.exe`?  If it's a non-Win32 app, it *will* run in a window; so just `exec("netsh ...");`  Still, it may need admin privilege.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a Windows question rather than a Java question, but what you're looking for is [`runas.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: I read your link, but I really don't know how to do it, can you post some codes with it shows what I want, pleas?

Comment: @Sasha open a command window, and run "runas" - that will dump the command line parameters available.